# How do we remove an organization owner who is no longer with us?

Tags: trello

We have a Trello organization for our company, and one of our team has recently moved on to pursue another opportunity. He was marked as an organization owner, and now it seems that there's no way to remove him from the organization at all. Obviously this presents a problem.

How do we remove his ownership and/or membership from the organization and the organization's boards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case that the person is still with the team, they can give ownership to another member of the organization, and then "Give up Ownership of Organization" (from the organization profile page)

If there are multiple organization owners, then one of the owners can remove the other one.

If the person isn't with the team, and was the only owner of the organization (and it sounds like this is the case you're in), you'll need to contact **support@trello.com**.